# htaccess url rewrite with RegEx

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to redirect some url, but got some problem with it. The urls like:

```
/sample?back=my-account
/sample?back=history
/sample?back=addresses
```

And need to redirect to

```
/sample
```

My last try was this (but didn't work):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?back=history$
RewriteRule ^sample$ /sample [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What about `^sample/?back=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this fix:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^back=
RewriteRule ^sample$ /sample? [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `http://example.com/sample?back=my-account` to `http://example.com/sample`.

Apparently, your condition was not met since the query string starts with `back`, and to get rid of the query string, you need to add `?` to the end of replacement string.

[Apache Module mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

> When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution
>   string with just a question mark.